# Checkbox not true when checked for every panel in my recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

so I created a recyclerview and I am inflating an xml file into that recyclerview, inside my customxml file I have a checkbox, however, when I click on the checkbox it always gives me the true statement for the first panel in the recyclerview and the rest are false whats up with that?

```
  public void CheckBox(View view) {
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
        System.out.println("SET TO CHECKED");

    }

else{
        System.out.println("SET TO UNCHECKED");
        }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? When is this `CheckBox()` method called?

Comment: The typical convention is to start method names with lowercase. I had to do a double-take because this almost looked like a constructor from the name.

Comment: its an OnClick listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in a `RecyclerView`, multiple child views will have the same `id`. I suspect that `final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);` does not return the checkbox that you actually want. It sounds like it always returns the first one in the list, not the one which is clicked on. Since `CheckBox()` is the `onClick` listener for your checkboxes, there is no reason to call `findViewById()`. You can simply use the `view` which is sent as a parameter:

```
Checkbox checkbox = (Checkbox)view;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
     final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
     if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
         checkBox.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: how is that useful? that is literally exactly what I wrote in a different variation

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.

Comment: You still have not explained how the code you give will help the OP.

Comment: First step was this public void itemClicked(View v) {
        //code to check if this checkbox is checked!
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v;
        if(checkBox.isChecked()){

        }
    }

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Before your answer.

Comment: But i have thiked tha I have overlooked RecyclerView.